# I want to change UIButton Image when tapped on it

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrolstate

I have 2 buttons in header on CollectionViewController. When i tap on one of them i'm changing an image of this buttons using UIControlState -> .normal .selected.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    engSwitchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abc"), for: .normal)
    geoSwitchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abg"), for: .normal)
    engSwitchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abc2"),for: UIControlState.selected)
    geoSwitchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abg2"), for: UIControlState.selected)


    engSwitchButton.tag = Language.english.rawInt
    geoSwitchButton.tag = Language.georgian.rawInt
}



@IBAction func languageSwitchTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected



    selectedLanguage = Language(rawInt: sender.tag)!
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

I want the button which i tapped first, get back to .normal state when i'm changing state of 2d button with tapping on it.

Answer (score 0):

To change a button image on tap you should use the `UIControlState.highlighted`.

So change:

```
engSwitchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abc2"),for: UIControlState.selected)
    geoSwitchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abg2"), for: UIControlState.selected)
```

To this:

```
engSwitchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abc2"),for: UIControlState.highlighted)
    geoSwitchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abg2"), for: UIControlState.highlighted)
```

Comment: when I use .highlighted it just works during tapping. Thats why I'm using .selected, because when i tap button 1 it must stay .selected and when i tap button 2 i want it to become .selected and button 1 must get back to .normal

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func yourFirstButton(_ sender: Any) {
    firstButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourButtonPressedImage")!, for: .normal)
    secondbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourNormalImage")!, for: .normal)


}
```

and in your second buttons @IBAction method just switch the images for the buttons

```
 @IBAction func yourSecondButton(_ sender: Any) {
     secondButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourButtonPressedImage")!, for: .normal)
     firsBbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourNormalImage")!, for: .normal)


 }
```

Comment: the problem im facing right now (as I literally just implemented this) is setting it as the default image once I press the button